# How make Rabl works with ActionController::Metal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I've took this [post](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/04/08/api-with-ruby-on-rails-useful-tricks/) like basis but receive empty response every time. What's wrong?

Basic controller:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  include AbstractController::Helpers

  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::Rendering
  include ActionController::Renderers::All
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::Instrumentation

  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views"

  respond_to :json

end
```

Controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

RABL template:

```
object @user

attributes :first_name
```

Comment: So what data do you serializing to json?

Comment: Where do you define `@settings` variable for your RABL template? Try to use defined in controller `@user` instead.

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in example. I use @user in template

Answer (score 0):

Try to include:

```
include ActionController::ImplicitRender
```

I've been testing it with rails 4.0.4 and ruby 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This is minimal setup that works for me in Rails **4.1.8**:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering # Basic rendering

  include ActionView::Rendering # Finds view using lookup_context and append_view_path

  include ActionController::Rendering       # Support respond_to and render formats
  include ActionController::MimeResponds    # MIME type for respond_to
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender  # Implicitly calls render so you don't
  include ActionController::Instrumentation # Sets Content-Type header amongst others

  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views" # Get views from here
end
```

Feel free to add modules to your taste.